# sock_create vs. sock_create_lite

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel

I hope to implement web server inside kernel and find two functions which look similar. I don't get point by review source because I lack background knowledge.

Could anyone point out what difference between `sock_create()` and `sock_create_lite()`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the commit message of [the patches](https://lkml.org/lkml/2004/5/7/77) with which this function has been added:

> The purpose of this is to allow sockets created by the kernel in this
>   way to be passed through the LSM socket creation hooks and be labeled
>   and mediated in the same manner as other sockets.

So, basically, the purpose of the *sock_create_lite()* is to make socket more LSM friendly.

Comment: Thanks for your info, I know a new knowledge, LSM.